# How can I use moderntimeline without moderncv?

Tags: tikz-pgf, moderncv, moderntimeline

How can I use `moderntimeline` without having to use `moderncv` as the document class?

The following code is what I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\tlmaxdates{2001}{2012}

\begin{document}
\tlcventry{2012}{0}{Test}{}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```

More specifically, what modifications to `moderntimeline` are required to get it to run with a more general document class?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from "using" `moderncv` as the documentclass, but to refrain from using any of the moderncv commands while creating your own cv. You will miss the commands of e.g. `article`, but I doubt you would need them to create a cv.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not familiar with `moderntimeline`, but you need to add some definitions of lengths, and commands from `moderncv.cls` and some of its styles (`moderncvstyleclassic.sty`, for example); you also need to provide some colors.

At least, to make the main commands `\tlcventry`, `\tllabelcventry`, `\tldatecventry`, and `\tldatelabelcventry` available, and to behave as they would do in the classic style for `moderncv`, in another class you need something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[firstyear=1999,lastyear=2012]{moderntimeline}

\makeatletter
\colorlet{color0}{blue}
\colorlet{color1}{olive}

\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\labelitemi~}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\tlmaxdates{2001}{2012}
\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tlcventry{1999}{2002}{WYSIWYG User}{Unnamed Company}
{Somewhere}{}{Tried hard to typeset documents}

\tllabelcventry[magenta]{2002}{2003}{July--November 2002}
{Scribus Student}{GNU School}
{The Internet}{}{Tried Scribus for a short while}

\tldatecventry[brown]{2011}{Trusted TeX.SX user}{}{tex.stackexchange.com}
{The Internet}{}{Achived 20k reputation on TeX.SX}

\tldatelabelcventry[blue!70!black]{2011}{Christmas 2011}{Happy TeXer}{}{Home}
{Townville}{}{Received Don Knuth’s \emph{3:16} as a gift.}

\end{document}
```

[image]