# Customization on moderntimeline

Tags: article, moderntimeline

Referring to [artcile with moderntimeline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76071/how-can-i-use-moderntimeline-without-moderncv/76076#76076), I tried to implement the same. I wish to have the entries which are in the tabular form:
[image]
To like this(similar structure):
[image]
But, with the use of `moderntimeline`, package.
Here is what I have done till now. I need help in improving it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}

\makeatletter
\colorlet{color0}{blue}
\colorlet{color1}{olive}

\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\labelitemi~}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\tlmaxdates{2001}{2012}
\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth\relax}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}
[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\rule[0ex]{2cm}{4pt}}
{1em}
{}



\begin{document}
\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\tllabelcventry[blue]{2011}{2015}{2011}
{B.Tech.}{Computer Science and Engineering}
{Pondicherry Engineering College}{}{Aggregate CGPA 8.5}
\tldatelabelcventry[blue!70!black]{2011}{2011}{Higher Secondary}{}{Petit Seminar Higher Sec. School}
{92\%}{}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. To keep consistency, use the same lengths everywhere; i.e., instead of fixed, hard-coded lengths for the rule and spacing in the customized `\section` command, use `\hintscolumnwidth` and `\separatorcolumnwidth`, as in

   ```
   \titleformat{\section}
   [block]
   {\normalfont\bfseries}
   {\rule[0ex]{\hintscolumnwidth}{4pt}}
   {\separatorcolumnwidth}
   {}
   ```
2. Since this is a CV, it seems reasonable to suppress indentation globally (by setting `\parindent` to `0pt`); if this is not desired, then use a `\par\noindent` in the definition of the elements which shouldn't be indented (`\cventry`, for example). Which option is to be used will depend on your actual intent, but my code contains both possibilities so you can decide.
3. For the timelines, use years that lie between the declared range; I mean, in your code you had

   ```
   \tlmaxdates{2001}{2012}
   ```

   so the maximum expected year was 2012, but you were using 2015 for one of your entries. In the code below I changed to

   ```
   \tlmaxdates{2001}{2015}
   ```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % to suppress indentation globally

\makeatletter
\colorlet{color0}{blue}
\colorlet{color1}{olive}

\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\labelitemi~}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \par\noindent% not required if indentation has been suppressed globally
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth\relax}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}
[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\rule[0ex]{\hintscolumnwidth}{4pt}}
{\separatorcolumnwidth}
{}

\tlmaxdates{2001}{2015}

\begin{document}

\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\tllabelcventry[blue]{2011}{2015}{2011}
{B.Tech.}{Computer Science and Engineering}
{Pondicherry Engineering College}{}{Aggregate CGPA 8.5}
\tldatelabelcventry[blue!70!black]{2011}{2011}{Higher Secondary}{}{Petit Seminar Higher Sec. School}
{92\%}{}{}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Update

In a comment it has been requested to use a shading for the colored bar instead of a solid color and to move the bar slightly to the left; the shading can be achieved using the `left color`, `right color`, `middle color` keys for a standard TikZ horizontal shading in the optional argument; the bar can be moved to the left using a smaller (for example,`2010.5` or any other suitable value) in the first mandatory argument instead of `2011`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{moderntimeline}

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} % to suppress indentation globally

\makeatletter
\colorlet{color0}{blue}
\colorlet{color1}{olive}

\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\labelitemi~}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \par\noindent% not required if indentation has been suppressed globally
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth\relax}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}
[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\rule[0ex]{\hintscolumnwidth}{4pt}}
{\separatorcolumnwidth}
{}

\tlmaxdates{2001}{2015}

\begin{document}

\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\tllabelcventry[left color=blue,right color=white]{2010.5}{2015}{2011}
{B.Tech.}{Computer Science and Engineering}
{Pondicherry Engineering College}{}{Aggregate CGPA 8.5}
\tldatelabelcventry[blue!70!black]{2011}{2011}{Higher Secondary}{}{Petit Seminar Higher Sec. School}
{92\%}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @subhamsoni why didn't you mention these "little changes" from the beginning? Why should the first date move to the left when you stated that the start year is 2011 (and what is "a few pixels")?

Comment: few pixels say 5 to 6

Comment: @subhamsoni please see my updated answer.